# Passing UIImage to JS using the native Trigger.IO API

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uiimage, trigger.io

I'm using an instance of ABAddressBookRef to access the ios address book. Ultimately I'd like to return a NSDictionary that contains names, phone numbers, and a thumbnail image. It's this last one that's giving me trouble. I can successfully include all the rest.

Here is just that UIImage being added to the dictionary `contact` with `thumbnail` as its key.

```
UIImage* contactThumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData:(__bridge NSData *)ABPersonCopyImageDataWithFormat(person, kABPersonImageFormatThumbnail)];
NSDictionary *contact = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          contactThumbnail, @"thumbnail", nil];
```

According to the [Trigger.IO Docs](https://trigger.io/docs/current/api/native_modules/api_methods.html) I'm allowed to return a `NSString`, `NSNumber`, `NSDictionary` or `NSArray`. How would I go about returning an image? Should I convert it, just point to it, what other options exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've never worked with Trigger.IO, but I'll bet when they say you can use NSString, NSNumber, NSDictionary, or NSArray, they mean ONLY those classes. A dictionary that contains objects of types not on that list, such as UIImage, won't work. That's how JSON data serialization generally works.

The solution to that problem is to serialize the image, probably into Base64 data and include that Base64 string within the dictionary, instead of the image. You can then use a `data:` URL within your JavaScript to reconstruct the image.

Comment: Hi Neal, thanks for the answer, just seeing this now for some reason. But how will the Javascript read a encoded UIImage?

Comment: `NSString *dataUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"data:image/png;base64,%@", base64ImageData];`